# Is there a web app that validates XML?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have a plain old XML document and an XML schema document.  Is there a simple web app that can validate whether the former conforms to the latter?  I'd rather not go with a heavy solution if I don't have to.

(Would someone retag this, please?  I hate to be a bad tagger, but I don't have the rep to create new tags and all the relevant tags I can think of would be new.)

EDIT:
Great suggestions so far, but now I'm looking at a schema with `include` tags.  Is there a web app that can handle those, or am I now asking too much?

Comment: I think you can also try XMLSpy by Altova. Not a online app but way too good.

Comment: That's kind of like me asking "how can I cross this river without a boat?" and you saying "try a sailboat"... but yeah, I've used XMLSpy in the past, it is good, just not what I was looking for with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of web applications which will validate an XML document against a particular schema.

1. http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/
2. http://www.xmlvalidation.com/
3. http://www.xmlme.com/Validator.aspx
4. http://www.xmlforasp.net/SchemaValidator.aspx

I think it's a case of picking and using the tool which has the interface that you like the most as they all do the same job.